# How can change eventLimit without refreshing the page in order to show the effect of different eventLimit

Tags: fullcalendar

I think by clicking on the button to display the calendar view `eventLimit` with different parameters, because there are a number of events on the page is a user added or modified, but not saved to the server. Users need to switch to a different view of events limit, which is in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsy0718/Lp8dacc0/3/)

Answer (score 1):

To change options when the calendar is already rendered you need to destroy the calendar first, change the option, then build the calendar again.
You can do it like this:

```
var options = $('.calendar').fullCalendar('getView').options;
options.eventLimit = false;
$('.calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
$('.calendar').fullCalendar(options);
```

### [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp8dacc0/4/)

Comment: yeah,but when users has changed or add some events,your destroy the calendar,so calendarData  and some other datas like date will lose...

Comment: I've edited the answer to be more specific to your requirements.

Comment: - first, options is the default configuration, not changed,for example,the `defaultDate` is '2015-06-01',when i clicked the next month,`$('.calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')` will get '2015-07-01',but the options's date still '2015-06-01', - second, when i add a events at '2015-06-03' and `renderEvent',this event don't save at server,when i destroy and build the calendar,the event at '2015-06-03' will lose.  so the calendar can't destroy. - My current practice is  to remind users to save when the calendar's events has changed and use 'sessionStorage’ save the changed 'date'

Comment: @fsy0718 I see. This is more of a workaround because dynamically change options is not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to change options dynamically now exists.

You don't have to destroy the calendar.

The syntax is `calendar.setOption('eventLimit',false)` to set the limit and `calendar.getOption('eventLimit')` to see what it is.

I wanted to have a button to expand/collapse all events on button click so I made a custom button like this:

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar($("#calendar"), {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'interaction', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
    height: 700,
    displayEventEnd: true,
    customButtons: {
        eventLimitButton: {
            text: 'Expand/Collapse All',
            click: function() {
                if(!calendar.getOption('eventLimit'))
                    calendar.setOption('eventLimit',5); //I set the limit to 5
                else
                    calendar.setOption('eventLimit',false);
            }
        }
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today eventLimitButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    buttonText: {
        today: "Today",
        dayGridMonth: "Month",
        timeGridWeek: "Week",
        timeGridDay: "Day",
        listWeek: "Weekly List"
    },
    //...
```